# SemigroupK operation to combine multiple Fibers

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fibers

Consider the following code:

```
import cats.effect._
import cats.syntax.semigroupk._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object TestFiber extends App {
  implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] =
    IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
  implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)
  
  //prints before1
  IO(println("before1")).attempt.start.flatMap(_.join).unsafeRunSync()
  //prints before2
  IO(println("before2")).attempt.start.flatMap(_.join).unsafeRunSync()
  //prints what?
  (
    IO(println("before1")).attempt.start <+>
    IO(println("before2")).attempt.start
  ).flatMap(_.join).unsafeRunSync()

}
```

As expected, the first and the second example prints `before1` and `before2` correspondingly.

My expectation for the third example was that the resulting Fiber `IO[Fiber[IO, Either[Throwable, Unit]]]` produced by the `SemigroupK` operation is completed as soon as both of the `Fiber`s are completed so both `before1` and `before2` should have been printed.

Unlikely

```
(
  IO(println("before1")).attempt.start <+>
  IO(println("before2")).attempt.start
).flatMap(_.join).unsafeRunSync()
```

prints the only `before1`

and

```
(
  IO(println("before2")).attempt.start <+>
  IO(println("before1")).attempt.start
).flatMap(_.join).unsafeRunSync()
```

prints the only `before2`.

Is it the expected behavior? What is the correct way to get a `Fiber` that is completed as soon as both of the `Fiber`s completed?

UPD: `Traverse`ing a `List` of `Fiber`s is an option, but it seems pretty cumbersome.

Comment: `combineK` will run each `IO` sequentially until the first one that succeeds. If you want to run two `IOs` in parallel you can try with `parMapN` so `(io1, io2).parMapN { (_, _) => () }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez So `combineK` is actually `race` and does not do `combine`ing `Fiber`'s result. That's not really obvious...

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez BTW `Parallel` isn't strictly speaking necessary.

Comment: If parallel is not strictly necessary then just `mapN` them or `traverse_` them as you said. If you want parallelism then `parMapN` or `parTraverse_` them. - So, it is not actually a `race`, it just tries the left one and if it succeeds it returns it, if not it just returns the right one. Yeah, it is not immediately obvious at the beginning, but if we remember that `combineK` has to combine two arbitrary `F[_]s` without looking into their contents, then the implementation makes sense and it is actually the most natural one. Also, this behaves exactly the same as with **Options**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Indeed, I just tried it, `Either` also behaves this way.